# setNeedsDisplay only gets called once

Tags: iphone, objective-c, drawrect, method-call, setneedsdisplay

In my code I want to "animate" a delay of drawing a line, so after adding a new line to the view, I call setNeedsDisplay - which works fine once.

Inside the drawRect method I draw the line and call a method of the line to increment the line-lengthl. Now I want to call setNeedsDisplay again to redraw the line - so it get's an animation of "growing"..

But it only calls setNeedsDisplay once & never again, except I add another line.
I also tried to call a method in this class, which calls setNeedsDisplay, to make sure you can't call it inside of drawRect..

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    for(GameLine *line in _lines) {

        if(line.done) {
            CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 5.0f);
            CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, lineColor);

            CGContextBeginPath(c);
            CGContextMoveToPoint(c, line.startPos.x, line.startPos.y);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, line.endPos.x, line.endPos.y);
            CGContextStrokePath(c);
        }else {
            CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 5.0f);
            CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, delayColor);

            CGContextBeginPath(c);
            CGContextMoveToPoint(c, line.delayStartPos.x, line.delayStartPos.y);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, line.delayEndPos.x, line.delayEndPos.y);
            CGContextStrokePath(c);

            [line incrementDelayLine];
            [self setNeedsDisplay];
        }
    }
}
```

**_lines** is a NSMutableArray with the GameLine objects (nonatomic, retain) property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need an animation - start a timer, once it's fired - adjust whatever line parameter you want and call `setNeedsDisplay`

Answer (score 5):

It is expected.

When you call setNeedsDisplay, you mark the view as needing to be redrawn. OK. The system gets it. 
*And it will be done the next time the main loop of your app runs*.

If you really want to refresh the view **now** call:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate: [NSDate date]];
```

just after `setNeedsDisplay`.

Indeed, [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) states (emphasis mine):

> When the actual content of your view changes, it is your
>   responsibility **to notify the system** that your view needs to be
>   redrawn. You do this by calling your view’s **setNeedsDisplay** or
>   setNeedsDisplayInRect: method of the view. **These methods let the
>   system know that it should update the view during the next drawing
>   cycle.** Because **it waits until the next drawing cycle** to update the
>   view, you can call these methods on multiple views to update them at
>   the same time.

Also, see these SO questions:

- [How to force a view to render itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408234/how-to-force-a-view-to-render-itself)
- [Is there a way to make drawRect work right NOW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739748/is-there-a-way-to-make-drawrect-work-right-now/4766028#4766028) (same concerns as you)

Comment: I added a "NSLog(@"Count: %d", [_lines count]);" to the drawRect before the for-loop, it appears a couple of times before adding a line - then one time again & after that none times..

Comment: @Christian'fuzi'Orgler Once you have called `setNeedsDisplay` the system won't take any other call into account until the view is redrawn (*i.e. until your application main loop runs*). This is because you already made it clear the view should be redrawn **next time the modal loop runs**. If you want the view to be redrawn each time you call `setNeedsDisplay`, use the code provided in my answer.

Comment: Note: beware that calling `setNeedsDisplay` in `drawRect:` can lead to  cyclic calls resulting in really bad performances.