# Force custom view to redraw (or invalidate) using a timer

Tags: ios, swift2

I've created a custom widget, which is animated. Now my problem is that I can't redraw the view, when the corresponding data gets updated.

Just don't hold anything against me in the code. This is my first piece of code in swift and I haven't worked with neither swift nor with Objective-C :-D

And also I've read the following questions, but they didn't help me:

[How to force a view to render itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408234/how-to-force-a-view-to-render-itself)

[what-is-the-most-robust-way-to-force-a-uiview-to-redraw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503761/what-is-the-most-robust-way-to-force-a-uiview-to-redraw)

p.s. : I can see the output of `print(digit.phase)` in the console.

p.s.s: I've also used `performSelectorOnMainThread` for calling the `setNeedsDisplay` function

The code:

```
import UIKit

struct Digit {
    var targetDigit: Int
    var currentDigit: Int
    var phase: Float
}

@IBDesignable class RollerCounter: UIView {
    var view: UIView!
    var viewRect: CGRect!
    var intNumber: Int
    var digits = [Digit]()
    let baseY = 20
    var timer: NSTimer?

    @IBInspectable var number: Int {
        get {
            return intNumber
        }
        set(number) {
            intNumber = number
            digits = []

            var tempNumber:Int = intNumber
            while tempNumber > 0 {
                digits.append(Digit(targetDigit: tempNumber % 10, currentDigit: Int(rand()) % 10, phase: 0.0))
                tempNumber /= 10
            }
        }
    }

    //init
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        // set properties:
        intNumber = 1111
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // setup the thing!
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        intNumber = 1111

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // setup the thing
        setup()
    }

    // Inital setup
    func setup() {
        let viewRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 280, height: 40)
        view = UIView(frame: viewRect)

        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]

        addSubview(view)

        self.setNeedsDisplay()

        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.0)
    }

    func animate() {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.016, target: self, selector: Selector("tick"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func tick() {
        for var digit in digits {
            digit.phase += Float(rand() % 100) / 100
            print(digit.phase)
        }

        setNeedsDisplay()

        //TEST: Also tested this
//      if let rect = viewRect {
//          drawRect(rect)
//      } else {
//          viewRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 280, height: 40)
//          drawRect(viewRect
//      }

    }


    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
        var tempNumber: Int = number
        let strTempNumber = String(tempNumber)

        var index: Int = 1
        let width = Float(rect.width)
        let charWidth: Float = Float(rect.width) / Float(strTempNumber.characters.count)
        let charHeight: CGFloat = 36

        let color = UIColor.blackColor()
        let font: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: charHeight)!
        let paraStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paraStyle.lineSpacing = 6.0
        let skew = 0.1

        let textAttribs = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color,
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paraStyle,
            NSObliquenessAttributeName: skew,
            NSFontAttributeName: font
        ]

        for digit in digits {

            let strCurrentDigit: NSString = String(digit.currentDigit) as NSString
            let strNextDigit: NSString = String(digit.currentDigit - 1) as NSString

            let xPos = width - Float(index) * charWidth
            let yPos = Float(baseY) + Float(charHeight) * digit.phase

            let point: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: Int(xPos), y: Int(yPos))
            strCurrentDigit.drawAtPoint(point, withAttributes: textAttribs)

            let nextDigitYPos = yPos - Float(charHeight) * 1.2
            let nextDigitPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: Int(xPos), y: Int(nextDigitYPos))
            strNextDigit.drawAtPoint(nextDigitPoint, withAttributes: textAttribs)

            index++
            tempNumber /= 10
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry folks. My bad :-(

There's nothing wrong with the invalidation system. Here's what's wrong:

```
for var digit in digits {
            digit.phase += Float(rand() % 100) / 100
            print(digit.phase)
        }
```

As it turns out, the changes to `phase` only get reflected in the local digit instance inside the for loop

But just to be clear, the `setNeedsDisplay()` call inside the `tick` method is crucial for the view to be updated.