# Why isn't my UIImageView object drawn in real-time?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, drawing

The following `UIImageView` is drawn on my ViewController's window only after I exit the
`-(void)playOn:(UIViewController*) currentViewController` method. Why is that? How can I make it so that I can draw on my ViewController from *inside* that method *while* that method is executing?

CellPainter.m

```
-(void)paintGoodCellonViewController:(UIViewController*)playingViewController
{
    int x = 32*(xAxis - 1);
    int y = 384 - (32* yAxis);

    UIImageView* myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:goodCell];
    myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y, 32, 32);
    [playingViewController.view addSubview:myImageView];
}
```

Game.m

```
-(void)playOn:(UIViewController*) currentViewController
{    
    [currentPainter paintGoodCellonViewController:currentViewController];

    while(!self.stopButtonPressed)
    {
        // code...
    }
}
```

MyViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)enterButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [currentGame performSelectorInBackground:@selector(playOn:) withObject:self];
}

- (IBAction)giveUpButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    currentGame.stopButtonPressed = YES;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to force `UIView` redraw:

```
[myView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: Do you mean I call `[myImageView setNeedsDisplay];` right after `[playingViewController.view addSubview:myImageView];` in the above setting, or right before that?

Comment: Call it after you add the view to your UI. On the other side, you may want to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4775803/730701).