# Making transparent video on iOS

Tags: ios, core-graphics, video-capture, avfoundation

I have two mp4 movies. One that has the actual video and one with the alpha values. My intention is that the first movie will get a transparent look, by merging it with the second one, where the second one will be the mask of the first one.

I know how to do this: with the CGImage alpha and blending tools. But I don't know how to get the exact frames of the videos. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or does somebody have an alternative idea?

Thanks!

Dries

Comment: AVAssetReader would give you each raw frame of the video. It would also be in a format ideal for use with core graphics. Take a look at the AVFoundation programmers guide, and this post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049207/reading-samples-via-avassetreader)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into some of the augmented reality sample apps out there.  They are doing real-time calculations based on each frame.

[This link is a good place to start](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2010/10/22/gpu-accelerated-video-processing-mac-and-ios).

Answer (score 0):

Try [this link](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) - great framework for creating image filters. In this framework you also can create video stream filtering from camera or filter already recorded video. Hope this help.