# Possible to use AV Foundation to crop a video?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, avfoundation, avcam

I am trying to crop videos both taken in my app and uploaded from the user's photo library. I am looking to crop every video to be the size of the iPhone 5s screen (I know that sounds dumb, but that's what I need to do).

Can I do this using the AV Foundation framework or do I need to use Core Video? I've made multiple attempts with AV Foundation and gotten nowhere.

Also if you could link to any helpful tutorials or code samples that would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Objective-C and working on an app designated for iOS 7+.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Use `AVAssetReader` to open your video and extract `CMSampleBuffers`
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049207/reading-samples-via-avassetreader)

2) Modify `CMSampleBuffer`:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493583/ios-scale-and-crop-cmsamplebufferref-cvimagebufferref)

3) Create `AVAssetWriter` and add modified `CMSampleBuffers` to it's input
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150219023016/http://www.developers-life.com/create-movie-from-array-of-images.html)
In this article `CVPixelBuffer` is used as an input to `AVAssetWriter` 
using adapter. You actually don't need an adapter because 
you have `CMSampleBuffers` 
ready you can add them straight 
to the input  using `appendSampleBuffer:` method.